# WAZUH All Commands monitor

Tags: kibana, audit-logging, intrusion-detection, ossec

How to monitor each and every command executed by user, even in sudo level.
I have configured audit rules and they are appearing in audit.logs, but I want to view each command timely from server to Kibana/wazuh manager.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfbcQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Auditd share complete commands and users UID too with wazuh if configured properly.
So I just added those columns from list in Kibana and now data is apearing fine.